# Express Session with www and non-www url

Tags: node.js, session, express

I currently resolve mySite.com and www.mySite.com to the same server. What path setting do I use in the session options to ensure I'm only creating a single session that can be "shared" between those two urls?

```
app.use ( session ( {
    store : new RedisStoreSession(),
    secret: 'keyboardCat',
    cookie: { maxAge: 3.156e+10 },
    path: '/'  //this is the default - i'm not setting anything yet
} ) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `domain` parameter in `cookie` with a leading `.` to allow the cookie for *all* subdomains (including www):

```
app.use ( session ( {
  store : new RedisStoreSession(),
  secret: 'keyboardCat',
  cookie: { maxAge: 3.156e+10, domain: '.example.org' },
  path: '/'  //this is the default - i'm not setting anything yet
} ) )
```